# Undefined local variable or method 'place'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

There is the following code:

```
@places.each do |place|
%tr
    %td= place.name
    %td= place.address
    %td= place.latitude
    %td= place.longitude
    %td= t(place.type)
    %td= link_to t(:destroy), place, method: :delete
    %td= link_to t(:edit), edit_place_path(place)
```

As you can see, it's code with HAML/Rails. But I've got 'undefined local variable or method 'place') for the first row in 'each' enumerator (place.name). How can I fix it? What's the trouble?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with this code. Is it from a view template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the proper haml syntax:

```
- @places.each do |place|
  %tr
    %td= place.name
    %td= place.address
    %td= place.latitude
    %td= place.longitude
    %td= t(place.type)
    %td= link_to t(:destroy), place, method: :delete
    %td= link_to t(:edit), edit_place_path(place)
```